# 2 questions about a solution Equal sides of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Question: Take an array with integers and find an index `N`
where the sum of the integers to the left of `N` is equal to the sum of the integers to the right of `N`. If there is no index that would make this happen, return -1. Let's say you are given the array `{1,2,3,4,3,2,1}`: Your function `equalsides()` will return the index `3`, because at the 3rd position of the array, the sum of left side of the index (`{1,2,3}`) and the sum of the right side of the index (`{3,2,1}`) both equal `6`.

One working solution I found online is

```
function findEvenIndex(arr)
{
    var left = 0, right = arr.reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0);

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(i>0) {
           left =left+ arr[i-1];
        }
        right =right- arr[i];
        if(left == right) 
           return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I am not able to explain the following two lines of code, any help would be appreciated!

1. Why  write `if i>0` in
   in the first line in the for loop
2. Why  write `i-1` in the line `left = left + arr[i-1]`

Comment: In regards to "Why write...?" can you elaborate on why not?

Comment: "One working solution I found online is..." is not encouraging as you being a motivated programmer. Where is your own solution?

Comment: It's an interesting question nonetheless

Comment: my solution didnt work brother, I had a different approach as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71543463/equal-sides-of-an-array-in-js/

Comment: What do you expect if given array will be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ....]`? Please tag me when you will answer

Comment: @EzioMercer it doesn't matter, because the question want to find an index not the first index, so this code would return `index = 1` which is a valid answer. But still, this wouldn't work with an array of size 1.

Answer (score 2):

Well the `if(i>0)` is required, because, arrays can't have negative indexes in JS. and `i-1` is required, because, you want to add elements to the left of the balance position to the left item, not including the balance position. Though I do believe, this is a better solution:

```
function findEvenIndex(arr){
    let left = 0, right = arr.reduce( (a,b) => (a+b), 0);
    for(let i in arr){
        right -= arr[i];
        if(right == left) return i;
        left += arr[i];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Arguably it's the same code, but, this has only one if statement and is a bit more apparent. Hope this helped :-)